# Creating distorted/dark/disturbing samples on stage

Tags: gear, live, sampling, samples

In the last 3 years, I have created what we call "samples" for a metal album for a band here in Montreal. The samples are distorted, loud and dark sounds of around 1 minute to fill the silence between the songs and sometimes added over track to create a very disturbing ambiance. Some of these samples are loopable. When they do shows, they put these samples on a foot pedal sampler and they can start/stop them whenever they want.

I have created these sound with Cubase 6, FL Studio, lots of plugins and the most important, recordings of real sound to which I add distortion, slow motion, reverb, layers, etc.. until it reach a good level of madness :)

My friend in that band asked me if I could join them live and create most of the sounds live. I know it's possible but I have no idea what kind of gear I would need to do this. As an example, you can check the band "Neurosis". There is a man using keyboard and lots of other gear to produce dark and disturbing sound live...

Any help pointing me out what kind of gear/software I would need to create live sound like that will help me a lot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check out the glitchmachines and inear display plugins.  They are amazing for being both weird and wonderful!

Filtering is also a good way.  For example the chaos created by Trent Reznor on the end section of his song "The Great Destroyer" was created largely in part with Metasonix gear. I won't get into this crazy gear...you have to check it out for yourself.  Weird, unique and expensive...but right up your alley.

Remember you can use ableton's vocoder as a filter also.  You can get some crazy results with this method.  Glitch, Turnado and Effectrix are also pretty cool.

Also don't forget about Reaktor.  And finally...if you feel brave, try your hand at circuit bending!

More important that the gear is your mindset using it.  If you approach gear in unconventional ways you will get unconventional results.  Remember there are no rules!

Answer (score 1):

With software, you're probably looking at Ableton Live, specifically the 'Max for Live' portion of the program. 
https://www.ableton.com/en/live/max-for-live/

With hardware, you'll need a more portable audio interface, a controller to perform with (i.e. Akai APC40, Novation Launchpad, etc), and a small mixer if it isn't part of your audio interface or controller.